# "Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer" is grayed out on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, remote-access

I just reinstalled Windows Server 2008 R22 on my Dell PowerEdge 2950 server. I am attempting to configure the server to be able to allow remote access from another computer on the network.

The "Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer" option under system properties in the "Remote" tab is grayed out.

I checked the group policy to make sure that "Require user authentication by using Network Level authentication" is not configured or disabled and I tried both without effect.

Any thoughts on what might be the issue with allowing remote assistance to this machine would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you set a password to your account?

Comment: Did you check "Allow users to connect remotely using Terminal Services"? You may see this in here:

GPEDIT.MSC -> Computer configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Remote Desktop Services | Remote Desktop Session Host | Connections.

Answer (score 6):

The Remote Assistance feature needs to be installed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - the feature appears to be not installed by default on 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

If it's greyed out then it's almost certainly being overridden by a Group Policy setting. I can't think of any other scenario where the GUI would not allow you to select the desired setting.

Answer (score 0):

you can install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50042 then download